# How to manage file sharing with dependencies across team members?

Tags: texturing, materials

I just joined a team where previously only one person worked to create models. Now we have two, and soon more. My question is somewhat two parts.

1) As part of my on-boarding, I'm working with models and scenes already created by the first guy. However, all of the files he shares with me are missing materials and textures. Yes, he could separately share all of the texture image files and I could re-build the links, but that is super time consuming. Is there a way to ensure that texture files are packaged up with the .blend and can be shared together?

2) Are there services which simplify file sharing among team members specifically tailored for blender? Are there any existing blender plugins which can connect with github and pull and sync files there? How do most people manage sharing lots of blender resources between multiple people? I've seen the blender sync options, but that seems mostly geared towards one person who works on multiple computers and wants to sync preferences and settings. (If this question is too "discussion" based, feel free to ignore it, or point me to a discussion board or article or something?)

Comment: Always setup a self contained project folder containing all project files, also use relative paths whenever possible. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos ! Great explanation post. At least I can ask the OG to make all his links relative before sharing, and I can lay down the law for proper file trees in the future.