# Archiving blender files (long term) for later reuse

Tags: blend-files

I've made a few basic blender animations.
Now I want to store these animations in an archive in case I would need them again in 3 years or so (on maybe a different pc).

Which settings should I apply? What should I look for when archiving? etc...
I'm aware that *File > External Data -> Automatically pack into blend* exists but it doesn't seem to work with video.

In photoshop (back in the days, I guess it is still that way) if you hide the layers before saving your file. The resulting output file on disk is a lot smaller, which is better for archiving/backups. Such tips are also welcome.

All tips and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work with video" -> video textures? video strips in vse? video from animation output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving all files to a new computer. My concern is Links](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links)

Comment: video that I use in animations to render (e.g. explosions are made from a video file)

Comment: Blender files can be used as they are for archiving.  Simply append them into later projects and extract the items you need with CTL-C/CTL-V.

Video file extensions can be renamed to non video extensions 
(e.g.) .4pm for mp4, avk for avi, etc. They will then be accepted as image files with which you can texture a plane and pack it's 'image'.