# Moved folders, now PNGs are pink, how do I restore?

Tags: image, blend-files

I decided to clean up my desktop and I moved all the folders into one folder, including the folder holding all my Blender files.  I opened a Blender file and saw that the objects that are textured with a PNG are now pink.  I believe this is because Blender lost track of the PNGs when I moved the folder.  Some of the objects are textured with a PNG series (movie).  They are also pink.  Is there any way I can get Blender to find those PNGs without having to do a System Restore on my computer? I tried moving the folder back to the desktop but that did not seem to help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links/56689#56689

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select **File** -> **External Data** -> **Find Missing Files**.

The file browser will open, find folder with missing files here. Repeat this with all folders with textures.