# is it possible to keep the texture attached to my project?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, image, uv-image-editor

every time i remove a texture from a file it also vanish from my project and it get replaced with a pink texture instead
is there a possible way to keep the texture attached to my project even if i removed them from my PC ?

Comment: Textures and other images used in the project are not saved as part of the .blend file by default unless they are **packed**.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that all the images you use are part of your blend file you can go into the *File* menu > *External Data > Automatically Pack Into .Blend*. If you don't want to make it automatic but just want to pack the current images, choose *Pack All Into .Blend*.

[image]

If you want to do it for just one or several images, you can go in the *UV Editor* or *Image Editor*, select the image you want, and *Image* menu > *Pack*.

[image]