# How do I open the same Blender file on two computers?

Tags: texturing, image, blend-files

I am attempting to work on blend files at work and at home, by using the same file location for the PBR textures. Unfortunately, find missing files command is not very comprehensive and cannot locate the texture images in the directory.
I chose to use the C:\ drive on both machines rather than 'documents'.

[image]

Is there another way to do this?
It has each image folder in many subdirectories away from the main.
I have this python script but I don't know where blender is looking for the original if it is not right where it should look for the new.

```
%%
import bpy

images = bpy.data.images  

for img in images :
    if img.source == 'FILE' :
         img.filepath = img.filepath.replace('\\old_folder\\','\\new_folder\\')
         img.reload()

%%
```

Comment: Instead of using the same folder, try to pack all your assets inside the blend file See this : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but is there a way to have a common address between 2 PCs?

Comment: You could use a cloud service (Google, one drive, mega, Dropbox)

Comment: This sounds like a needlessly convoluted workflow https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links

Comment: How is this a convoluted workflow? I have hundreds of PBR textures. Each blend file may use most of them. How about those textures all stay put and I just call on them for every blend file? "C:\poliigon texture\" should equal "C:\poliigon texture\" no matter which machine I am on